# Why am I getting error "Client with IP address x.x.x.x isnt allowed to connect to this MySql server" when trying to connect to MySql from Django?

Tags: django, mysql-python

I am trying to create tables for my models in this full stack project (Django/React). After I run the python manage.py migrate command I'm expecting to see:

Migrations for X:

```
   X\migrations\0001_initial_py
      - Create model Departments
      - Create model Employees
```

Instead I get the following error: (9000, "Client with IP address 'X' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server."

```
I have tried the command pip install pymysql
then edited the settings.py file adding 
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mytestdb',
        'USER': 'testadmin@mytestmysql',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXXXXXX#',
        'HOST': 'mytestmysql.mysql.database.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com',
        'PORT': '3306'
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL permissions are such that you have to specify 'user'@'host' when defining privileges.  My guess is that you didn't set the MySQL database user up correctly.

[Read here to understand what I'm referring to.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help @RiverRook. I was able to connect to MySQL from Django by doing the following.

Comment: My pleasure.  I hope my answer was beneficial to you.